# jQuery Show div on hover no working

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have a group of divs inside a tab structure that have 3 separate classes. "office", "office+#" and depending what is chosen in the back-end ("available", "availableFrom", "occupied". I need these divs to show when hovered. At the moment, all I'm trying to do is get the div to actually show on hover but nothing seems to be working that I've tried. At the moment I have this, but have tried multiple different things. I'm still learning jQuery so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Ground Floor /</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="true"><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">First Floor /</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Second Floor</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1" class="groundFloor tab ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
        <img src="http://concepts/10highstreet/wp-content/themes/10highstreet/img/groundFloor.jpg">
        <div class="office office1 availableFrom">
            <div class="date">14 March 2013</div>
        </div>
        <div class="office office2 availableFrom">
            <div class="date">19 April 2013</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2" class="firstFloor tab ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" role="tabpanel" style="" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
         <img src="http://concepts/10highstreet/wp-content/themes/10highstreet/img/firstFloor.jpg">
         <div class="office office3 availableFrom">
            <div class="date">10 May 2013</div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office3-1 availableFrom">
            <div class="date">10 May 2013</div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office4 available">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office5 available">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office6 available">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office7 available">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office8 available">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office9 availableFrom">
            <div class="date">06 June 2013</div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office10 availableFrom">
            <div class="date">28 February 2013</div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office10-1 availableFrom">
            <div class="date">28 February 2013</div>
         </div>
         <a class="office office11 occupied">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-3" class="secondFloor tab ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
         <img src="http://concepts/10highstreet/wp-content/themes/10highstreet/img/secondFloor.jpg">
         <div class="office office12 occupied">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office13 occupied">
            <div class="date"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="office office14 occupied">

         </div>
         <div class="office office15 occupied">

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$('a.office').mouseover(function(){
            div = $('div.office');
            div.stop().animate({visibility: visible}, 150);
}).mouseout(function(){
            div.stop().animate({visibility: hidden}, 150);
});
```

and CSS

```
.ui-tabs ul {
display:block; 
clear:both; 
height:40px; 
list-style-type:none; 
margin:0; 
padding:0;
}

.ui-tabs ul li {
display:block; 
float:left; 
list-style-type:none; 
padding-right:5px; 
font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
font-size:1.4em; 
font-weight:100;
}

.ui-tabs ul li a:link, .ui-tabs ul li a:visited {
color:#7a7989;
}

.ui-tabs ul li.ui-state-active a:link, .ui-tabs ul li.ui-state-active a:visited {
color:#03c2f9;
}

.ui-tabs .tab {
clear:both; 
height:700px; 
width:998px; 
margin:0 auto;
}

.office {
visibility:hidden;
}

.office .date {
display:none;
}

.office1 {
position: relative;
top: -256px;
left: 282px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 185px;
width: 192px;
}

.office2 {
position: relative;
top: -435px;
left: 529px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 178px;
width: 184px;
}

.office3 {
position: relative;
top: -244px;
left: 177px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 193px;
width: 89px;
}

.office3-1 {
position: relative;
top: -553px;
left: 282px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 95px;
width: 130px;
}

.office4 {
position: relative;
top: -498px;
left: 301px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 139px;
width: 142px;
}

.ui-tabs .tab .office5 {
position: relative;
top: -617px;
left: 450px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 120px;
width: 79px;
}

.office6 {
position: relative;
top: -754px;
left: 533px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 137px;
width: 89px;
}

.office7 {
position: relative;
top: -890px;
left: 627px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 137px;
width: 89px;
 }

 .office8 {
position: relative;
top: -1360px;
left: 365px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 127px;
width: 139px;
 }

.office9 {
position: relative;
top: -1487px;
left: 282px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 169px;
width: 76px;
}

.office10 {
position: relative;
top: -1657px;
left: 550px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 78px;
width: 133px;
}

.office10-1 {
position: relative;
top: -1870px;
left: 695px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 208px;
width: 162px;
}

.office11 {
position: relative;
top: -1861px;
left: 549px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 89px;
width: 138px;
}

.office12 {
position: relative;
top: -266px;
left: 576px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 166px;
width: 131px;
}

.office13 {
position: relative;
top: -386px;
left: 376px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 136px;
width: 89px;
}

.office14 {
position: relative;
top: -522px;
left: 273px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 136px;
width: 100px;
}

.office15 {
position: relative;
top: -643px;
left: 176px;
opacity: 0.6;
height: 106px;
width: 92px;
}

.available {
background: #0C9;
}

.occupied {
background: #ea6969;
}

.availableFrom {
background: #c8c8c8;
}
```

Comment: link http://jsbin.com/oqutor/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your jQuery selector `a.office`, you probably want to use `div.office` since you want the divs to show up themselves on hover.

Comment: This is almost right. I assume you want the divs to appear when you mouseover over the links at the top.

Your selector is looking for an `a` tag with the class `office` which doesn't exist.  You should probably be using the selector `$('a.ui-tabs-anchor')`

That probably isn't the end of the story. You might want to use the jQuery tasks `.show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: Thanks, sorry I should have probably explained this a bit better. The a.office select was from before when I had changed the office div to a link but then changed it back, forgot to change it back in my jQuery.

What I'm trying to do is when you hover over the office div, I want that office div to show. Basically I have a map of Offices, when you hover over an office I want it to show whether it is Available, AvailableFrom or Occupied.